# How do I download/save a backup of OSX's "Enhanced Quality" system voices for future use?

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

I wipe and reinstall OS X about once ever few months—probably more than necessary if I'm honest with myself, but then, it has become my go-to way to fix problems, and I've become very fast at getting everything set up again.

There is however one thing I have to do after every reinstall that takes quite some time on my slow internet connection: re-downloading the "enhanced quality" version of the "Samantha" system voice (my personal favorite).

Is there any way I could back up this enhanced voice so that I won't have to re-download it every time I install OS X? Ideally, I'd like a simple .pkg file I can just double click to install. Such a .pkg file for "Enhanced Speech Recognition" can be downloaded [here](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/55/13/031-1940/chpuvr2ntbhisy2em872b4j6hsk71croja/SpeechRecognitionCoreLanguage_en_US.pkg), but I can't find anything similar for system voices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `CatalogVersion 2 ApplePostURL http://swpost.apple.com` in a browser. Or download one or several of the Apple update catalog files directly e.g:

- [10.9 catalog](https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog)
- [10.10 catalog](https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog)
- [10.11 catalog](https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog)

Open the file(s) with a decent text editor. Search the file for MLV_*locale*_*name* with locale: your preferred locale and name: the voice name.

E.g. searching for **MLV_it_IT_alice** will reveal:

```
        ...
        <key>031-11791</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ServerMetadataURL</key>
            <string>http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/44/20/031-11791/gm3k0mrgb2nhbw6nmomxgshi9cd36lv9ke/MLV_it_IT_alice.smd</string>
            <key>Packages</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Size</key>
                    <integer>264300527</integer>
                    <key>MetadataURL</key>
                    <string>https://swdist.apple.com/content/downloads/44/20/031-11791/gm3k0mrgb2nhbw6nmomxgshi9cd36lv9ke/MLV_it_IT_alice.pkm</string>
                    <key>URL</key>
                    <string>http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/44/20/031-11791/gm3k0mrgb2nhbw6nmomxgshi9cd36lv9ke/MLV_it_IT_alice.pkg</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>PostDate</key>
            <date>2015-01-22T18:33:08Z</date>
            <key>Distributions</key>
            <dict>
                <key>English</key>
                <string>https://swdist.apple.com/content/downloads/44/20/031-11791/gm3k0mrgb2nhbw6nmomxgshi9cd36lv9ke/MLV_it_IT_alice.dst/031-11791.English.dist</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        ...
```

containing the ServerMetadataURL and the direct pkg download URL: [MLV_it_IT_alice.pkg](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/44/20/031-11791/gm3k0mrgb2nhbw6nmomxgshi9cd36lv9ke/MLV_it_IT_alice.pkg)

Enter the pkg download URLs in a browser or a download manager to get all desired voices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a clone copy of your OSX into an external hard disk after you reinstall all your necessary softwares and system voice. This can be used as your future restore point whenever you want to reinstall your OSX. You will just need to clone back the external hard disk to your internal one whenever you want to reinstall and your stuff will all be ready.

There are guides available online to clone your mac.
http://www.cultofmac.com/48861/how-and-why-to-clone-your-mac-hard-drive-macrx/